# how to strict user to go parent JFrame

Tags: swing, jframe, jdialog

I want to make JFrame like JDialog box so user can not go outside the JFrame or parent JFrame. how can i make this. please help me.

This is my code:-

```
    TestBedForm n = new TestBedForm();
    JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
    dialog.setSize(n.getSize());
    dialog.setTitle("Design");
    dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    dialog.setModalityType(Dialog.ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
    dialog.add(n);
    dialog.setVisible(true);
```

Here TestBedForm is JFrame and now i want to open this as JDialog box so what is wrong with this code. can somebody help me.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add a JFrame into a Container. You will get RuntimeError. Try
    `dialog.add(n.getContentPane());`
instead of 
    `dialog.add(n);`

Comment: thanks for quick reply .but now cancel button on TestBedForm is not working basiljames..